# Is it valid to reuse a second view controller with dynamic cells to display elements of a different array in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I currently have 2 `table view controllers`. I've added two disclosure indicators on two static cells for marital status and home state (canton). The user clicks on one of both and is taken to another view controller where he makes the appropriate selection.

The code is currently working for marital status. My question is if here I could reuse the second view controller (i.e. the one with the dynamic cells) for the same purpose but utilising a different array (in this case an array with states' names). For me it is clear that I could simply add a new view controller and implement the states' list there. Here is a screenshot of the storyboard:

[image]

First View Controller code:

```
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController, DataEnteredDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var maritalStatusCell: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet var maritalStatusLabel: UILabel!



    func userDidEnterInformation(info: String) {

    maritalStatusLabel.text = "Marital Status: (\(info))"

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "maritalStatusSegue" {
            let sendingVC: SecondTableViewController = segue.destination as! SecondTableViewController
            sendingVC.delegate = self
        }
    }

}
```

Second View Controller code:

```
import UIKit

protocol DataEnteredDelegate {
    func userDidEnterInformation(info: String)
}

class SecondTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let maritalStatusArray: [String] = ["Single", "Married"]
    let cantonArray: [String] = ["ZG", "ZH", "BE", "LU", "AG"]
    var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate? = nil





    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  maritalStatusArray.count

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if delegate != nil {
            let information: String? = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.textLabel?.text
            delegate!.userDidEnterInformation(info: information!)
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }


    }




    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MaritalStatusCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = maritalStatusArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }



}
```

Does is make sense here to use the second table view controller for the states' list as well ? If yes, how can I implement that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the Same View controller for displaying the Array of your states' names which I think you have declared in `cantonArray`, what you need to do is declare a bool variable in `Second View Controller` (In case if you want to manage only two arrays, if you want to manage more arrays then declare an `enum`). Then in the segue get from which index that segue is fired, you can get the selected indexPath like this

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{

}
```

Now check the indexPath.row, if it is `0` then you have selected Marital State so you need to show `maritalStatusArray` array so make the bool variable `true` if you get `indexpath.row = 1` then make that variable `false`

Now in Second View Controller add a condition as per the bool variable and show the data from that array like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MaritalStatusCell", for: indexPath)
    if showMaritalArray {
          cell.textLabel?.text = maritalStatusArray[indexPath.row]

    } else {
          cell.textLabel?.text = cantonArray[indexPath.row]

    }
    return cell

}
```

This is how you can declare `enum`

```
enum SelectedRow {
    case MaritalStatus
    case States
    case ThirdRow
}

var selectedRow = SelectedRow.MaritalStatus
```

Comment: Can you add an example of using the enum in your answer?

Comment: Hi Rajat, thanks for your answer. As I am a beginner to Swift, I'm not sure I get what you said. So the boolean variable is showMaritalArray ? I don't understand where I should declare if ´let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{}´....